# apply camera effects with videobrush in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have been playing around with an example on how to create a grayscale effect from a live videobrush feed from a wp7 camera using the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202982(v=vs.92).aspx . I was wondering if anyone knows how to create other effects as well, just as sepia, polarized, negative etc. If so, could you point me to any sites or code that would allow me to create this? Note, I am fairly new to the camera API in WP7 so any assistance would be very beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to rewrite the ColorToGrey() method to do the effect you want.

A quick google suggests that you could do a [sepia effect](http://www.smokycogs.com/blog/image-processing-in-c-sharp-getting-that-old-time-effect-with-sepia/) or [negative](http://www.gutgames.com/post/Creating-Negative-Images-using-C.aspx).

Other tips
The sample should be editable directly. Just remember to set the source of the video brush (or it takes a long time to work out what is happening - I did that). The camera is mounted in landscape mode, so you might need to rotate it to get it into the right orientation.

Comment: @Thanks gbanfill I'll have to check it out later today. About the rotation, I've noticed in landscape left the orientation is correct, and then portrait (rotation = -90) and landscape right (rotation = -180) assuming rotation = clockwise (is that correct?). Also, I would like to use the front facing camera I'm assuming since mounted in the opposite direction all rotations are opposite to get the correct orientation (I do not have a front facing camera to test this on my phone, unfortunately)?